# how to get pygame button to register only one click?

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent

I'm making a game in pygame with a pressable button, but I want it to do only one thing when clicked.  The code below prints "button pressed" for as long as you hold it down.  What's an elegant way to change this code to make it only print that once per click?

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def makeButton(x,y,width,height):
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        if click == (1,0,0):
            print "button pressed"


square = pygame.Rect((0,0), (32,32))

while True:
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    makeButton(square.left,square.top,square.width,square.height)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.fill((55,155,0), square)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple and more efficient way to do what you want would be to explicitly check for `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events and only do the mouse event processing when necessary. You can also streamline the logic in `makeButton()` by using pygame's `Rect` class which knows how to do collision detection.

Here's what I mean:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def makeButton(cur, rect):
    if rect.collidepoint(cur):
        print "button pressed"

square = pygame.Rect((0,0), (32,32))

while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.fill((55,155,0), square)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:  # left mouse button?
                makeButton(event.pos, square)
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed!  I was state checking and I should have been event handling.  This will make my game so much easier to code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just having a method, I'd make a button class and instantiate it for each button you need. You're also attempting to create your own mouse event handling that runs every time the game loop does, but it's better practice in pygame to pass mouse info to such a button object only on a mouse event. MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and MOUSEBUTTONUP event types will be passed to the event queue whenever there is a click. To create the behavior you describe you could have your button action execute only if the mouse is within the button bounds on the MOUSEBUTTONUP event. [This](http://pygame.org/ftp/contrib/input.html) page provides a good intro into pygame input handling and [this](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/10/30/creating-a-button-ui-module-for-pygame/) page provides a detailed (though somewhat advanced) discussion of creating a general button class in pygame.

Comment: thanks sunday, I didn't realized there was a difference between state checking and event handling.  This all makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but this worked for me.
I went from a code like this:

```
..........ygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if x+ button_width > mouse[0] > x and y + button_height > mouse[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, ([x, y],[button_width, button_height])

    if click[0] == 1:

        if bn == 0:
            button_0()
        if bn == 1:
            button_1() 
        if bn == 2:
            button_2()
        if bn == 3:
            button_3()
        if bn == 4:
            button_4()
        if bn == 5:
            button_5()
```

**Adding a global variable  is_clicked = False with the other
variables at the beginning of the program, a global statement
in the function, and 2 if statements, (6 lines of code).
Changed to this:**

```
# (msg, (x, y coordinates),width,height,inactive color, active color, 
        #  button number) all the info to place and label the buttons.
```

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, bn): 
    global is_clicked 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+ button_width > mouse[0] > x and y+ button_height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, ([x, y],[button_width, button_height]))

```
    if click[0] == 1 and is_clicked == False:
        is_clicked = True

        if bn == 0:
            button_0()
        if bn == 1:
            button_1() 
        if bn == 2:
            button_2()
        if bn == 3:
            button_3()
        if bn == 4:
            button_4()
        if bn == 5:
            button_5()

    if click[0] == 0 and is_clicked == True:
        is_clicked = False # set is_clicked back to False after mouse 
                           # button up.
```