# Making button function run once

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent

I can't work out to make the button function run once when clicked. Whenever the mouse button is down it runs through the function loop until released. I only want to run through the loop once per click. Here is the code:

```
def Button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, lightgrey, (x, y, w, h))
            if action == "undo":
                print("hey")  
            if action == "reset":
                for row in range(6):
                    for column in range(7):
                        board[row][column] = 0          
            elif action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x, y, w, h))
```

print("hey") prints roughly 3 times if you click as fast as you can as it is running through the loop repetitively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get pygame button to register only one click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300690/how-to-get-pygame-button-to-register-only-one-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` will return True for as long as the mouse is held down. Assuming this checks every frame, it's going to return 1 or True for multiple frames, thus causing your print statement to occur multiple times.

`if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:`

This line you commented out is the one you should be using. It only activates when the mouse is actually clicked, but not *while* it is being held down. Note that for this to work, you must have a loop like `for event in pygame.event.get()` before this line.

So what you basically need to do is remove `click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` and replace `if click[0] == 1` with the line you commented out. Hopefully this works :)

Comment: I added what you said, and it does work partially. It does print once when clicked, but if I was to click the button again it doesn't run through the loop at all. Meaning if I click once it would print 'hey' but if I was to click it again nothing prints

Comment: That's peculiar. Did you place the for loop as I said? If you did, where did you put it?