# How do I make it so that my variable only goes up by one when i click a button in pygame and also how I can make it so that the text updates

Tags: pygame

Im trying to make an Idle Clicker Game using pygame for school and Im running into some problems and id really appreciate some help

I need some help with my program, mainly I have two problems, for one when I click the "Upgrade Whetstone Button" While the variable Whetstone level goes up the text won't, and because of the way ive done it I cant Just blit some text onto the screen so I'd like some help there and secondly when i press the upgrade button and i have it printed on the screen the variable Whetstone Level goes up by more than one and I want it to go up one level for one click and so i was wondering what i could do to change it so that it only goes up by one level

Thanks in advance

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
colours = {"White" : (255, 255, 255), "Black" : (0, 0, 0), "Red" : (255, 0, 0), "Blue" : (0, 0, 255), "Green" : (0, 255, 0)}
clickdamage = 1
Whetstone_Level = 0

class Screen():
    def __init__(self, title, width=400, height=600, fill=colours["White"]):
        self.title=title
        self.width=width
        self.height = height
        self.fill = fill
        self.current = False
        
    def makeCurrent(self):
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)
        self.current = True
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
         
    def endCurrent(self):
        self.current = False
        
    def checkUpdate(self):
        return self.current
    def screenUpdate(self):
        if(self.current):
            self.screen.fill(self.fill)
            
    def returnTitle(self):
        return self.screen
    
class Button():
        def __init__(self, x, y, sx, sy, bcolour, fbcolour, font, fontsize, fcolour, text):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.sx = sx
            self.sy = sy
            self.bcolour = bcolour
            self.fbcolour = fbcolour
            self.fcolour = fcolour
            self.fontsize = fontsize
            self.text = text
            self.current = False
            self.buttonf = pygame.font.SysFont(font, fontsize)
        def showButton(self, display):
            if(self.current):
                pygame.draw.rect(display, self.fbcolour, (self.x, self.y, self.sx, self.sy))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(display, self.bcolour, (self.x, self.y, self.sx, self.sy))
                
            textsurface = self.buttonf.render(self.text, False, self.fcolour)
            display.blit(textsurface, ((self.x + (self.sx/2) - (self.fontsize/2)*(len(self.text)/2) - 5,(self.y + (self.sy/2) -(self.fontsize/2) - 4))))
        def focusCheck(self, mousepos, mouseclick):
            if(mousepos[0] >= self.x and mousepos[0] <= self.x + self.sx and mousepos[1] >= self.y and mousepos[1] <= self.y + self.sy):
                self.current = True
                return mouseclick[0]
            else:
                self.current = False
                return False
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, dx, dy, filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = dx
        self.rect.y = dy
      
   

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    
        

menuScreen = Screen("Menu Screen")
screen2 = Screen("Screen 2")

win = menuScreen.makeCurrent()


done = False
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

clickdamagelevel = Button(160, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], str(Whetstone_Level))
clickdamageupgrade = Button(10, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], "Whetstone")
shopButton = Button(125, 500, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "Shop")
DungeonButton = Button(125, 500, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Blue"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "Dungeon")
hitboxButton = Button(80, 50, 280, 400, colours["White"], colours["Red"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "")
goblin = Enemy(0 , 20, "images\goblin-resized.png")
goblin2 = Enemy(0 , 20, "images\goblin.jpg")
toggle = False
while not done:
    menuScreen.screenUpdate()
    screen2.screenUpdate()
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if menuScreen.checkUpdate():
        screen2button = shopButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        attack = hitboxButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        hitboxButton.showButton(menuScreen.returnTitle())
        goblin.draw(menuScreen.screen)
        shopButton.showButton(menuScreen.returnTitle())
        if attack:
            print("hitpoints - click damage")
        if screen2button:
            win = screen2.makeCurrent()
            
            menuScreen.endCurrent()
            
    elif screen2.checkUpdate():
        returnm = DungeonButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        DungeonButton.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        clickdamageupgrade.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        clickdamagelevel.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        if clickdamageupgrade.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click):
            Whetstone_Level += 1
            print(Whetstone_Level)
            clickdamagelevel.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        if returnm:
            win = menuScreen.makeCurrent()
            screen2.endCurrent()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            done = True
    
    
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300690/how-to-get-pygame-button-to-register-only-one-click?rq=1) will help

Comment: @user16038533 Umm so that did help however if i use mousebutton down how do i use it on an range of co-ordinates rather than the whole screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN to register one mouse click per mouse button down.
In your case, you can use your `mouse_click` button variable. Move your event loop before all of the if statements.

```
    mouse_click = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_click = True  

    if menuScreen.checkUpdate():
         #...
```

This also means your `foucsCheck` member function should return `mouseclick` and not a subscript of it.

```
def focusCheck(self, mousepos, mouseclick):
     if(mousepos[0] >= self.x and mousepos[0] <= self.x + self.sx and mousepos[1] >= self.y and mousepos[1] <= self.y + self.sy):
         self.current = True
          return mouseclick #mouseclick[0]
```

That fixes the problem of registering single click.

For the second problem, it would be ideal if you could change just the text, but since your button class does not allow that, you can recreate the button with the updated  `Whetstone_Level` variable every time it is clicked. That being said, i would recommend you to modify your class slightly to facilitate this.

```
if clickdamageupgrade.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click):
      clickdamagelevel = Button(160, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], str(Whetstone_Level))
```

Updated code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
colours = {"White" : (255, 255, 255), "Black" : (0, 0, 0), "Red" : (255, 0, 0), "Blue" : (0, 0, 255), "Green" : (0, 255, 0)}
clickdamage = 1
Whetstone_Level = 0

class Screen():
    def __init__(self, title, width=400, height=600, fill=colours["White"]):
        self.title=title
        self.width=width
        self.height = height
        self.fill = fill
        self.current = False

    def makeCurrent(self):
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)
        self.current = True
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

    def endCurrent(self):
        self.current = False

    def checkUpdate(self):
        return self.current
    def screenUpdate(self):
        if(self.current):
            self.screen.fill(self.fill)

    def returnTitle(self):
        return self.screen

class Button():
        def __init__(self, x, y, sx, sy, bcolour, fbcolour, font, fontsize, fcolour, text):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.sx = sx
            self.sy = sy
            self.bcolour = bcolour
            self.fbcolour = fbcolour
            self.fcolour = fcolour
            self.fontsize = fontsize
            self.text = text
            self.current = False
            self.buttonf = pygame.font.SysFont(font, fontsize)
        def showButton(self, display):
            if(self.current):
                pygame.draw.rect(display, self.fbcolour, (self.x, self.y, self.sx, self.sy))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(display, self.bcolour, (self.x, self.y, self.sx, self.sy))

            textsurface = self.buttonf.render(self.text, False, self.fcolour)
            display.blit(textsurface, ((self.x + (self.sx/2) - (self.fontsize/2)*(len(self.text)/2) - 5,(self.y + (self.sy/2) -(self.fontsize/2) - 4))))
        def focusCheck(self, mousepos, mouseclick):
            if(mousepos[0] >= self.x and mousepos[0] <= self.x + self.sx and mousepos[1] >= self.y and mousepos[1] <= self.y + self.sy):
                self.current = True
                return mouseclick
            else:
                self.current = False
                return False
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, dx, dy, filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = dx
        self.rect.y = dy



    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)



menuScreen = Screen("Menu Screen")
screen2 = Screen("Screen 2")

win = menuScreen.makeCurrent()


done = False
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

clickdamagelevel = Button(160, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], str(Whetstone_Level))
clickdamageupgrade = Button(10, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], "Whetstone")
shopButton = Button(125, 500, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "Shop")
DungeonButton = Button(125, 500, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Blue"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "Dungeon")
hitboxButton = Button(80, 50, 280, 400, colours["White"], colours["Red"], "arial", 20, colours["White"], "")
goblin = Enemy(0 , 20, "images\goblin-resized.png")
goblin2 = Enemy(0 , 20, "images\goblin.jpg")
toggle = False
while not done:
    menuScreen.screenUpdate()
    screen2.screenUpdate()
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    mouse_click = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_click = True

    if menuScreen.checkUpdate():
        screen2button = shopButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        attack = hitboxButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        hitboxButton.showButton(menuScreen.returnTitle())
        goblin.draw(menuScreen.screen)
        shopButton.showButton(menuScreen.returnTitle())
        if attack:
            print("hitpoints - click damage")
        if screen2button:
            win = screen2.makeCurrent()

            menuScreen.endCurrent()

    elif screen2.checkUpdate():
        returnm = DungeonButton.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click)
        DungeonButton.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        clickdamageupgrade.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        clickdamagelevel.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        if clickdamageupgrade.focusCheck(mouse_pos, mouse_click):
            Whetstone_Level += 1
            clickdamagelevel = Button(160, 10, 150, 50, colours["Black"], colours["Red"], "arial", 15, colours["White"], str(Whetstone_Level))
            print(Whetstone_Level)
            clickdamagelevel.showButton(screen2.returnTitle())
        if returnm:
            win = menuScreen.makeCurrent()
            screen2.endCurrent()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```